# How to force test fail in Codeception

Tags: php, testing, codeception

I am making WebServices tests with Codeception, here is my code:

```
//Making first query for getting needed parameter
$I->wantTo('Make something');
$I->sendPOST($this->route, [
    'token' => Fixtures::get('token'),
    'id' => Fixtures::get('some_id')
]);
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
$I->seeResponseContains('"error_message"');

//Then I get what I need with regexp
if (preg_match('/^.*\s(?<value_i_need>\d+)\.$/', $I->grabDataFromResponseByJsonPath('$.status.error_message')[0], $matches)) {
    $I->sendPOST($this->route, [
        'token' => Fixtures::get('token'),
        'id' => Fixtures::get('some_id')
    ]);
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
    $I->seeResponseIsJson();
    $I->seeResponseContains('"something"');
    $I->seeResponseContains('"something_else"');   
} else {
    //And if I don't get needed parameter with regular expression, here I have to force test fail
}
```

Does anybody know how to force test fail?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be useful if you could give us much more information. Firstly, is your test an acceptance, functional or unit test? More importantly, why would you want to force a test to fail? What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It is api testing. I need to force fail, for example, to check if some Object was created in DB

Comment: Still unsure of what type of test you are trying to run. Perhaps you could post your code of the test and of the bit of code you are trying to test.

Comment: You can just throw an exception new Exception('Your message here');

Answer (score 7):

You can use the fail action on your actor. i.e.

```
$I->fail('this test fails... just because');
```

Comment: I also use this function when using Codeception, thank you.

Comment: Has this method been removed? I don't have it in Codeception 4.1.31.

Answer (score 4):

You can mark your test as skipped or incomplete. Here is example:

```
public function tryToMakeAwesomeThings(ApiTester $I, Scenario $scenario)
{
    if ( ... ) {
        // do something
    } elseif ( ... ) {
        $scenario->incomplete();
    } elseif ( ... ) {
        $scenario->skip();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::fail()` or throw `PHPUnit\Framework\AssertionFailedError` exception.

Answer (score 2):

There is another problem with Codeception 4 and upper.
Method fail now in Assertion module https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Asserts
This module not included in codeception by default, you must install it separately.
When you install it, this module must be added in config file, such as "api.suite.yml"

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
  enabled:
    ...
    - \Codeception\Module\Asserts
```

After this, you need to rebuild codeception and this method appear to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use `assertInstanceOf()` from https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Asserts

Example:

```php
public function test_array_result() {
    /** @var Demo $demo */
    $demo = Common::get_which_class( $this->post_id );

    self::assertInstanceOf( Demo::class, $demo, 'Unable to instantiate the Demo class.');

    $x = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];

    $this->assertEqualSetsWithIndex( $x, $demo->get_result() );
}
```